# How to suggest edits for locked posts?

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions

I was looking at the question here:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/80469/19607

which is currently locked and was rejected for migration from Math SE.  I agree the question is not appropriate as is for our site.  However, there is a related question (how to find such schools) that I think would be appropriate and is of potential interest to the OP.

Unfortunately, I can neither edit nor comment at this point.  Is there a way I can suggest to the OP to ask this?  Note in this case the OP does not seem to have a clickable profile.

Comment: The fact that the OP does not have a clickable profile here probably means (my guess) that they have removed their subscription to Academia.SE, so I don't think that you can suggest anything to the OP directly from here. There is a user with the same name on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/168011/proofromthebook), but they might not even be the same person.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thanks. Do you know, if I had more rep, would I be able to comment on a locked post?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to comment on locked posts even with higher rep. if I understood it correctly the lock is automatic after the migration rejection. It seems related to [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157744/300001) on the main Meta. Mods will probably have more information,

Comment: You should be able to write your comment [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2030867/17111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rejected migrations are locked automatically on the target site.

However, they are *not* locked on the source site, so you can comment on [the post on the source site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030867/strong-schools-in-langlands-program). (Which would be more useful than commenting here even if it wasn't locked, since the OP does not have an account here and would not get any notification of your comment.)

Comment: Ah, now I understand.  I thought the message "migration rejected from" Math SE meant someone tried to migrate it from here to there, and that was rejected, not the other way around--as in the rejection came from Math SE.  If we rejected it I wouldn't have have expected it to show up in our active questions queue as it did.